# value checked from url radio tag

Tags: php, url

```
<?php
$gender = $_GET['gender'];
$mysql_query = "select * from gender where value='$gender'";
$result = $conn->query($mysql_query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="<?php echo $row['value'];?>">
<?php 
    echo $row['value'];
}
?>
```

Lets assume the url is :- `url.php?gender=male`
the value in database are male, female, children
how do I make the male checked when the URL is passed

Comment: our code says post, your text says get. which is it?

Comment: Sorry it is $_GET typo...

Comment: thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Ehsan-Khodarahmi you turned $_GET into $_POST...

Comment: @Jocelyn: It was approving a suggested edit & I fixed it up right now, thanks for reminding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set both checkbox's up and check the one that is set in the url

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" <?= (strtolower($_GET['gender']) === 'male' ? 'checked' : ''); ?>/>

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" <?= (strtolower($_GET['gender']) === 'female' ? 'checked' : '');?>  />
```

I have just used short hand if statements inside the elements to test content of the gender param.

**In response to your comment**

I started writing a response to your comment and once i knew i needed code example Ive moved it here:

Short answer yes you would need to do it for every field instance.

But there is a dynamic loop option.

You would need to be able to able to build an array from your query that contained for each input element the type, name, value, checked. the array would need to look something like this:

```
<?php 

    $inputs = [
        0 => [
            'type' => 'radio',
            'name' => 'gender',
            'value' => 'male',
            'checked' => true
        ],
        1 => [
            'type' => 'radio',
            'name' => 'gender',
            'value' => 'female',
            'checked' => false
        ]    
    ];
```

Now that your input array is defined you can loop through dynamically creating your inputs. Here I'm creating both inputs in a loop:

```
    <?php foreach($inputs as $inp): ?>
        <input type="<?= inp['type']; ?>" name="<?= $inp['name']; ?>" value="<?=$inp['name']; ?>" <?= $inp['checked'] ? 'checked' : ''; /> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Because you of the way you are passing the gender in the `URL` as  `GET` param you will probably have to go with my original answer at the top

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this solution. But what if I have lets say 10 or 20 columns in database. am I suppose to write the same things for all of them...

Comment: Thanks for the response.. It seems I dont have any choice but to use the early solution

Answer (score 1):

just put condition on input radio `<?php echo ($row['value']=='male' || $row['value']=='female' || $row['value']=='children' ) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>`

```
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="<?php echo $row['value']; ?>" <?php echo ($row['value']=='male' || $row['value']=='female' || $row['value']=='children' ) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>><?php echo $row['value']; ?>
```

and same for female and children

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this solution. But what if I have lets say 10 or 20 columns in database. am I suppose to write the same things for all of them...

Comment: @lazyme114 <?php echo ($row['value']=='male' || $row['value']=='female' || $row['value']=='children' ) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>

Comment: @lazyme114 use or condition